# Two SELECT .. INTO statements show the same results

Tags: mysql

I have two SELECT ... INTO  statements in a procedure. The problem is, both variables get filled with the same text at the end. Any ideas why?

```
DECLARE v_Title TINYTEXT;
DECLARE v_Category TINYTEXT;

SELECT title FROM titles_table WHERE id = 5 INTO v_Title;
SELECT category FROM categories_table WHERE id = 30 INTO v_Category;

SELECT v_Title, v_Category;
```

An example output: **"Category" | "Category"**, but it should be **"Title | Category"**

Comment: Are there only 1 row in titles_table for id = 5 and only 1 row in categories_table where id = 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after upgrading my version of MySQL (perhaps a bug). I upgraded to the newest version as of this date, and now it's working correctly (I made no changes to my code).

The version I had with the issues was: 5.7.10

I upgraded to: 5.7.17 , which works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If returning values of both variables are correct you could change a little bit your last `select` like:

```
 SELECT v_Title as Title, v_Category as Category;
```

and that is all.